# Combining 2 columns into 1 row

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a data as below:

```
ID   GroupID     from      To 

1      2          A        B 
1      2          B        C
```

I would like to combine it as "A/B/C" into a single value for 2(GroupID).

result that I needed:

A/B/C

and if

```
ID   GroupID     from      To 

1      2          A        C 
1      2          B        A
```

The result must be A/B/C/A

Thanks in advance.

Comment: couldn't understand your requirement?

Comment: I edited my question please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after working for 4 hrs I was able to find the solution, Try and let me know.

Create a formula `@Concat` and write below code and place in details:

```
Shared Stringvar firstcol;
Shared Stringvar seccol;

firstcol:=firstcol+{From}+"/";
seccol:=seccol+{To}+"/";
```

Now create one more formula `@Display` and place in footer (Group or Report) as per requirement.

```
Shared Stringvar firstcol;
Shared Stringvar seccol;
Local Stringvar third;
Local Numbervar i;
Local Stringvar final;
Local StringVar array store;

third:=firstcol+seccol;

store:=Split(third,"/");


For i:=1 to UBound(Split(third,"/")) Do
(

if (store[i]="")
then exit for;

if store[i] in final
then final:=final+store[i+2]+"/"
else final:=final+store[i]+"/"

);

Left (Replace(final,"//","/"), Length(Replace(final,"//","/"))-1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Siva I'll try your solution

Comment: Let me know whether it worked for you or do you have any issues